# Angular 2 - Auto-Routing SPA via CMS?

Tags: angular, express, content-management-system, angular2-routing

I'm looking at making a single page application with an integrated content management system, so that users can edit everything across the site, and even add new pages.

However it doesn't seem possible to have an SPA that can automatically route a new page upon the user creating said page from another page within the SPA.

The only way to do this, from what I can see, is to have the backend handle that and have it use angular-cli to make the components and edit the files within Angular, and then to rebuild and replace it's currents DIST files. Which is hecka' messy.

So I ask, is this even possible? And if so, how would you do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? In my experience, it has been far easier/cleaner to keep CMS logic and SPA logic separate. Then you can treat your CMS almost like a "content api" and expose endpoints that will return data for the SPA to display and render a page around.

Comment: @Exziled Right. But say if we have a 'Pages' section in our CMS, which contains  /home, /contact, /about etc - We can't have angular automatically create components/routes for those to be included in the SPA.

Answer (score 1):

This would really depend on what sort of ***new*** pages are you planning on creating.

If these new pages are something like a blog page that you're creating, you can set an id for each blog page and then get to the page based on the id. This id would then be leveraged to get the data for that page from an API.

But this would restrict how your pages would look. All of them would have a consistent look and feel which might not be what you're looking for.

For your specific use case, using React instead of Angular could help as it has [**Gatsby**](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/).

Comment: Right, yeah my pages would be their own thing, and not a set structure using tags to fill in content. I'll take a look at ReactJs/Gatsby, though I would prefer to stick with Angular since it's not owned by Facebook and is more of a standard